# Argument 1 missing or nil - Roblox Lua

Tags: roblox

I was making an ore that you could mine, but when I'm trying to mine it until its health will be 0, I should've been having 1 gem (it gives 1 gem when I mine it), but instead it gives error:

```
14:09:24.711  Argument 1 missing or nil  -  Server - Script:4
14:09:24.711  Stack Begin  -  Studio
14:09:24.712  Script 'Workspace.Gem.ClickDetector.Script', Line 4  -  Studio - Script:4
14:09:24.712  Stack End  -  Studio
```

Script 1 (game.Workspace.Gem.ClickDetector.Script):

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Parent.Health.Value = script.Parent.Parent.Health.Value - 1
    if script.Parent.Parent.Health.Value < 1 then
        workspace.GetOres.Gems:FireClient()
        script.Parent.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.Parent.CanCollide = false
        wait(9)
        script.Parent.Parent.Transparency = 0
        script.Parent.Parent.CanCollide = true
        script.Parent.Parent.Health.Value = 10
     end
 end)
```

Script 2 (game.Workspace.GetOres):

```
script.Gems.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    local leaderstats = game.Players.LocalPlayer:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
    leaderstats.Gems.Value = leaderstats.Gems.Value + 1
end)
```

And also, Script 2 is LocalScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are modifying the Gems leaderstat in a LocalScript and not the main Script because it is a hidden value and you only want the local player to see it.

You have three issues :

First, when your use the [RemoteEvent's FireClient](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireClient) function, you are communicating from the server down to a specific client. Because there can be many clients, you need to specify which client you are firing this message to. The error is telling you that the first argument is missing, that's because it is supposed to be a Player. You can easily get that Player from the [ClickDetector's MouseClick](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/ClickDetector/MouseClick) event. That looks like this :

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(playerWhoClicked)
    game.Workspace.GetOres.Gems:FireClient(playerWhoClicked)
```

Next, your [LocalScript](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript) won't actually receive the event. LocalScript's are only active in a handful of places, and it cannot be in the Workspace. So I would recommend that you move it to [StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterPlayerScripts).

Third, since the RemoteEvent was located inside that LocalScript, you'll also need to move that somewhere accessible to the server Script. I would recommend moving that to [ReplicatedStorage](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ReplicatedStorage). And you would just update the path to that events like this :

```
local getGemsEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.Gems
getGemsEvent:FireClient(playerWhoClicked)
```

Altogether, that looks like this :

```
local detector = script.Parent
local gem = script.Parent.Parent
local getGemsEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.Gems

detector.MouseClick:Connect(function(playerWhoClicked)
    gem.Health.Value = gem.Health.Value - 1
    if gem.Health.Value < 1 then
        getGemsEvent:FireClient(playerWhoClicked)
        gem.Transparency = 1
        gem.CanCollide = false
        wait(9)
        gem.Transparency = 0
        gem.CanCollide = true
        gem.Health.Value = 10
     end
 end)
```